# Jquery accordion collapsed on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create an expandable accordion using jquery. I am not able to figure out that how am I supposed to prevent it from expanding on page load. I have no idea of jquery,and any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
            <ul>
            <li class="expandable root">

                <label for=" Oraganization" class="active"> Oraganization</label> 
                <span class="pull-right oraganization active expand-icon glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span> 

                <ul id="accordion">
                    <li class="expandable">
                        <span class="expand-icon active glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span> 
                        <input type="checkbox" id="Manager-1"> 
                        <label for="Manager-1"> Manager-1</label> 

                        <ul id="accordion">
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="Sub-Manager-1"> 
                                <label for="Sub-Manager-1"> Sub-Manager-1</label> 
                            </li>
                            <li class="expandable">
                                <span class="expand-icon active glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span> 
                                <input type="checkbox" id="Sub-Manager-2"> 
                                <label for="Sub-Manager-2"> Sub-Manager-2</label> 

                                <ul class="accordion">
                                    <li>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="Associate-1"> 
                                        <label for="Associate-1"> Associate-1</label> 
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="Associate-2"> 
                                        <label for="Associate-2"> Associate-2</label> 
                                    </li>



                            <li class="expandable">
                                <span class="expand-icon active glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span> 
                                <input type="checkbox" id="Associate-5"> 
                                <label for="Associate-5"> Associate-5</label> 
                                <ul class="accordion">
                                    <li>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="Sub-associate-1"> 
                                        <label for="Sub-associate-1"> Sub-associate-1</label> 
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="Sub-associate-2"> 
                                        <label for="Sub-associate-2"> Sub-associate-2</label> 
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="Sub-associate-3"> 
                                        <label for="Sub-associate-3"> Sub-associate-3</label> 
                                    </li>   
                                    <li>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="Sub-associate-4"> 
                                        <label for="Sub-associate-4"> Sub-associate-4</label> 
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                </li>
                                </ul>
                                </li>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>


                    <li class="expandable">
                                <span class="expand-icon active glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> 
                                <input type="checkbox" id="Manager-2"> 
                                <label for="Manager-2"> Manager-2</label> 
                    </li>
                    <li class="expandable">

                                <span class="expand-icon active glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> 
                                <input type="checkbox" id="Manager-3"> 
                                <label for="Manager-3"> Manager-3</label> 
                    </li>                       

                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

JS File:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.expand-icon').click(function(){

    var elem = $(this);
    if(elem.hasClass('active')) {
        elem.removeClass('active');

        var subElem = elem.siblings('ul');
        var nestedElem =elem.siblings('ul').find('ul');

        if(nestedElem.length == 0) {
            subElem.slideUp('fast');
        }
        else {
            nestedElem.slideUp('fast',function(){
                subElem.slideUp('fast');
            });
        }
        $.when(elem.removeClass('glyphicon-minus')).then(function(){
            elem.addClass('glyphicon-plus');
        });
    }
    else {
        elem.addClass('active');
        elem.siblings('ul').slideDown('fast',function(){
            elem.siblings('ul').find('ul').slideDown('fast');   
        });
        $.when(elem.removeClass('glyphicon-plus')).then(function(){
            elem.addClass('glyphicon-minus');
        });
    }

});


$('.expandable :checkbox').on('change', function() {

    $(this).parent().find('li input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
    var sibs = false;
    $(this).closest('ul').children('li').each(function () {
        if($('input[type=checkbox]', this).is(':checked')) sibs=true;
    });
    $(this).parents('ul').siblings(':checkbox').prop('checked', sibs);

});
```

});

You an find the bootply at this link: http://www.bootply.com/1W8bSTnmx6

Comment: What do you mean 'collapsing'?

Comment: on given link, first accrordian row is expanded. What exactly you want to do?

Comment: Hi,I want that when page is loaded,the accordion should not be expanded,only the "location" label should be visible with plus sign on the right,when I click on the plus sign,the accordion should be expanded,with the nested elements to be collapsed with + sign on their left-as in the design. RIght now,the entire accordion is getting expanded on page load with minus sign

Comment: You shouldn't have multiple elements with the same `id` attribute. You should remove/rename the id="accordion"

Answer (score 1):

[**Fiddle Here**](http://www.bootply.com/vGoKbvfKtl)

This is because you have this first accordian open when loading it. To fix it, do a click operation on this at the time of load with `$($('#accordion .expand-icon')[0]).click();`. Check the working example here http://www.bootply.com/vGoKbvfKtl

Comment: Thanks for the reply,but I wanted everything to be collapsed on page load-including nested elements and "oraganization" with plus sign for all

Answer (score 0):

you are just displaying all the accordions when the page gets loaded since there is no hiding any where.

**According to your code Since only the first Accordion contains the data, it is getting displayed else every expandable div will get displayed.**

The solution for this is to add a hide class to the class accordion so that it does not display at  the beginning, the at the time of click function, you can remove that class and it gets displayed.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $('.expand-icon').click(function(){
  $('ul').removeClass('hide')
  var elem = $(this);
  if(elem.hasClass('active')) {
   elem.removeClass('active');
   
   var subElem = elem.siblings('ul');
   var nestedElem =elem.siblings('ul').find('ul');
   
   if(nestedElem.length == 0) {
    subElem.slideUp('fast');
   }
   else {
    nestedElem.slideUp('fast',function(){
     subElem.slideUp('fast');
    });
   }
   $.when(elem.removeClass('glyphicon-minus')).then(function(){
    elem.addClass('glyphicon-plus');
   });
  }
  else {
   elem.addClass('active');
   elem.siblings('ul').slideDown('fast',function(){
    elem.siblings('ul').find('ul').slideDown('fast'); 
   });
   $.when(elem.removeClass('glyphicon-plus')).then(function(){
    elem.addClass('glyphicon-minus');
   });
  }
  
 });
 
 
 $('.expandable :checkbox').on('change', function() {
  
  $(this).parent().find('li input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
  var sibs = false;
  $(this).closest('ul').children('li').each(function () {
   if($('input[type=checkbox]', this).is(':checked')) sibs=true;
  });
  $(this).parents('ul').siblings(':checkbox').prop('checked', sibs);
  
 });
  
 $('.organization').click(function(){
      $('.accordion')[0].click()
    }) 
});
```

```html
<ul>
 <li class="expandable ">
   
  <label for=" Oraganization" class="active"> Oraganization</label> 
  <span class=" organization active expand-icon glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span> 
  
  <ul id="">
   <li class="expandable">
    <span class="expand-icon glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> 
    <input type="checkbox" id="Manager-1"> 
    <label for="Manager-1"> Manager-1</label> 
    
    <ul class="accordion hide">
     <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="Sub-Manager-1"> 
      <label for="Sub-Manager-1"> Sub-Manager-1</label> 
     </li>
     <li class="expandable">
      <span class="expand-icon active glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span> 
      <input type="checkbox" id="Sub-Manager-2"> 
      <label for="Sub-Manager-2"> Sub-Manager-2</label> 
      
      <ul class="accordion">
       <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="Associate-1"> 
        <label for="Associate-1"> Associate-1</label> 
       </li>
       <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="Associate-2"> 
        <label for="Associate-2"> Associate-2</label> 
       </li>
       
      
     
     <li class="expandable">
      <span class="expand-icon active glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span> 
      <input type="checkbox" id="Associate-5"> 
      <label for="Associate-5"> Associate-5</label> 
      <ul class="accordion">
       <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="Sub-associate-1"> 
        <label for="Sub-associate-1"> Sub-associate-1</label> 
       </li>
       <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="Sub-associate-2"> 
        <label for="Sub-associate-2"> Sub-associate-2</label> 
       </li>
       <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="Sub-associate-3"> 
        <label for="Sub-associate-3"> Sub-associate-3</label> 
       </li> 
       <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="Sub-associate-4"> 
        <label for="Sub-associate-4"> Sub-associate-4</label> 
       </li>
      </ul>
      </li>
      </ul>
      </li>
     
    </ul>
   </li>

   
   <li class="expandable">
      <span class="expand-icon active glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> 
      <input type="checkbox" id="Manager-2"> 
      <label for="Manager-2"> Manager-2</label> 
   </li>
   <li class="expandable">
   
      <span class="expand-icon active glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> 
      <input type="checkbox" id="Manager-3"> 
      <label for="Manager-3"> Manager-3</label> 
   </li>      

  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the bootply,
 **[Bootply link for it](http://www.bootply.com/x7DaaI48uo)**

Comment: Hi,thanks for the reply. I need everything to be collapsed on Page load

Comment: Yes, that is happening since there is no bootstrap on it, it didn't collapse, I have added a bootply, please check now.